# Laravel 9: Login success returns white page

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a login and when I log in with correct login details, it just goes back to login. When I reload the login page, it redirects to authenticated page. This happens when I log in different user types.

My question is similar to this [Laravel login - After the login is successful, it does not remain and returns to the login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75626921/laravel-login-after-the-login-is-successful-it-does-not-remain-and-returns-to) but this doesn't work.

This is my session controller.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $userDetails = $request->validate([
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);


    if (Auth::attempt($userDetails))
    {
        $userType = Auth::user()->user_type;
        session()->regenerate();

        // ------------------when code starts on this line, error

        if ($userType == 3) {
            return redirect()->route('index');
        }
        else if ($userType == 2) {
            return redirect()->route('indexAgent');
        }
        elseif ($userType == 1) {
            return redirect()->route('indexAdmin');
        }
    }
    else{
        Auth::logout();
        Alert::error('Failed', 'Invalid login details.');
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

This is what my route looks like:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:3'])...rest of code
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:2'])...rest of code
Route::middleware(['auth', 'user-access:1'])...rest of code
```

My middleware:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $role): Response
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->user_type == $role)
    {
        return $next($request);
    }

    Auth::logout();
    Alert::error('Failed', $role);
    return redirect('/');
}
```